# How to configure SSO by SAML on Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

At first, I am new in SAML. Could somebody tell step by step, how to configure SSO on Drupal using simplesamlphp? Or how to test by "Test configured authentication sources"?

What I have now.

1. Installed [simpleSAMLphp Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth) module.
2. Add simplesamlphp library to my site (mysite/simplesamlphp).
3. Changed config.php
4. Added meta to saml20-sp-remote.php

   ```
   $metadata['name'] = array(
       'SingleSignOnService'  => 'url_login',
       'SingleLogoutService'  => 'url_logout',
       'certFingerprint'      => 'key'
   );
   ```
5. When I go to mysite/saml_login, I am return to login page on IdP. After login I return to my site (mysite/sso/login?params) with SAMLRequest and other GET-params. But site show page not fount error. On [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) it step 2.

So what I did wrong? May be I must set same page callback to handle this GET-params?

I also try to did this by simplesaml "Test configured authentication sources", but I got the same result.

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert, but I have had experience configuring simplesamlphp with wordpress. 
but i think there may be similarities.

below my step to configure to "Test configured authentication sources"

1. Extract Simplesamlphp into my web server

   `/opt/lampp/htdocs`         <-- myApp

   `/opt/lampp/simplesamlphp`  <-- simplesamlphp
2. Configure alias `simplesaml` on `apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
       DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
       ServerName localhost

       Alias /simplesaml /opt/lampp/simplesamlphp/www
       <Directory "/opt/lampp/simplesamlphp/www">
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
          Require all granted
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. modify `/opt/lampp/simplesamlphp/config/config.php`
4. modify `/opt/lampp/simplesamlphp/config/authsources.php`

   enable (uncomment) `example-userpass1` authsource

   *don't forget to enable `exampleauth` module with

   `touch /opt/lampp/simplesamlphp/modules/exampleauth/enable`
5. open authentication tab > click "Test configured authentication sources"
   then click `example-userpass` to test configured authsource.